# Can't access JS file inside index.html in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have angular app. I need to run simple JS script before akk angular stuff is bootstrapped. I can access images from index.html file like this

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="../../../assets/safari-pinned-tab.svg"/>
```

But I can't access JS file (see 404 error in browser)

```
<script src="../../../assets/startup.js"></script>
```

Why is so?

Comment: It depends how your back-end is configured to serve assets

Comment: The why is simple: Because the file can't be found there. There isn't enough information in your question to tell where it is or why you think it should be at that URL.